# How to increase SFDR value for Direct digital synthesizer simulation?

Tags: power-electronics, dds

I am following the code written in this article [code](https://cushychicken.github.io/direct-digital-synthesis-python-model/) and I am manipulating some numbers based on my application. I want to use a stm32 microcontroller to generate a sine waveform. I didn't understand a couple of things, like why such values are used in the code and how to optimize SFDR value?

1. what I understood is the smaller the value of Fout/Fs is, the smaller the M is, which means the more precise it becomes. Also, it is better that Fout is not the exact submultiple of Fs, according to [pg 8](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-085.pdf). But there seems to be other factors affecting the SFDR.
2. similarly, the length of phase array has chosen to be 2^20. I assume, the higher the better, but also it is expensive.
3. The truncation bits in the code is used 12 MSBS (32-20 in the code where right shift operator is used) and based on the tutorial I linked above, it should be around 13-15 MSBS? But is the truncation bit always around that range?
4. STM32 has DAC resolution of 12 bit and 128kb Flash memory and 36 Kb SRAM, we could take bit depth and ROM depth in the code (as linked in above article) = 2^12?
5. The SFDR for the above code is around -40dB.  As I understand, sfdr is the difference between the fundamental frequency and the highest spur. here in this image, I cannot see a pure fundamental frequency, or atleast there are multiple points which I don't understand.

[image: sfdr]

When I try to change the sampling rate and fout for some other value, keeping other numbers same, I get even worse sfdr value. Also, the same changing other parameters slightly. Could anyone explain how does one improve SFDR?

PS. I'd like to apologize that I couldn't add code snippets after each paragraph, for some reason, it didn't work for me here in stackexchange.

Comment: When you say *how to optimize SFDR value* do you in fact mean *how to maximize SFDR value*? What is the vertical/horizontal scale on your spectrum calibrated in? What frequency were you expecting to see? Is it 30 something? Did you view it on an oscilloscope?

Comment: Yes, how to maximize SFDR value. I have worked on the python code to just simulate and see the output. My desired output is 10KHz. The vertical is amplitude and the horizontral is frequency bins. It's the power spectrum I assume in the code.

Comment: This is two very different questions: 1) Purge quantization spurs using dithering (better suited for DSP.SE) or 2) reduce spurs due to hardware nonlinearity of the DAC?

Comment: I haven't used hardware yet. Just simulating in Python.

Comment: also, i found out that there is spectral leakage in my fft. Is it the reason for low SFDR?